# Multiple each and ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

so this is my setup: I am calling a .each on a number of elements and after a few checks I send an ajax request with some JSON data and on success I apply the server response as an attribute to each element(it is usually an id). After that I push the id to an array.

The problem is that obviously ajax requests are asynchronous and the function that uses the array of element ids fires before all ajax have had time to finish.

I've tried with .when and .then but the callback function keeps getting fired way ahead of the ajax.

Here is how my code looks( I've removed some unnecessary parts):

```
var order = [];

function sub(selector){

selector.each(function(){
    var out = {
        "some":"random",
        "stuff":"here"
    };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST" 
            url: "/test/url",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data:JSON.stringify(out),
            success:function(response){
                $(this).attr("data-response",response);
                order.push(response);
            }
        })
    })
}

$("#button").click(function(){
    $.when(sub($(".test"))).then(function() {
        console.log(order);
        //i have to run the sub function twice so the order doesn't return undefined
    });     
});
```

Comment: you can keep checking number of itmes in order array untill it is of same size as of selector.each. using setInterval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `when` acts on deferred objects, however sub doesn't return anything so `when` fires right away. So what you need to do is to collect all the deferred objects returned by the ajax calls and return them:

```
var order = [];

function sub(selector){
    var deferredList = []
    selector.each(function(){
        var out = {
            "some":"random",
            "stuff":"here"
        };
        var deferred = $.ajax({
                type: "POST", 
                url: "/test/url",
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data:JSON.stringify(out),
                success:function(response){
                    $(this).attr("data-response",response);
                    order.push(response);
                }
            })
        deferredList.push(deferred)
    })
    return deferredList;
}

$("#button").click(function(){
    $.when.apply($,sub($(".test"))).then(function() {
        console.log(order);
        //i have to run the sub function twice so the order doesn't return undefined
    });     
});
```

The reason to use `apply` and not `when` directly is that `when` doesn't accept array of objects as a parameter and `apply` provides us the work-around for this.

Comment: this also fires before all the ajax(all the values in the order array are undefined)

Comment: Works for me, it's possible that the problem in your code is someplace else

Answer (score 0):

The argument to `$.when()` should be a `Deferred`, but `sub()` doesn't return anything. This version returns an array of all the `Deferred`s returned by `$.ajax`, and calls `$.when` with them all as arguments; it will then wait for all of them.

```
var order = [];

function sub(selector){
    return selector.map(function(){
        var out = {
            "some":"random",
            "stuff":"here"
        };
        return $.ajax({
            type: "POST" 
            url: "/test/url",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data:JSON.stringify(out),
            success:function(response){
                $(this).attr("data-response",response);
                order.push(response);
            }
        })
    })
}

$("#button").click(function(){
    $.when.apply(this, sub($(".test"))).then(function() {
        console.log(order);
        //i have to run the sub function twice so the order doesn't return undefined
    });     
});
```

Comment: shouldn't be `success` a method of the returned object given by `$.ajax`?

Comment: `$.ajax()` returns a `jqXHR` object, which implements the `Promise` interface in addition to AJAX-specific methods like `.done()`.

Comment: i tried it and but it still fires before all the ajax has finished

Answer (score 0):

Your approach produces a whole lot of more server requests and will scale terribly. Since you want to wait for all results anyway, a much better solution would be to collect all data and send only one ajax request which returns an array of results for each data object.

Using a deferred object (as seen in other answers) then gives you the ability to use that result in a `when` statement.

Answer (score 0):

try to use a callback-function in success:

```
var order = [];

function sub(selector, callback){

selector.each(function(){
    var out = {
        "some":"random",
        "stuff":"here"
    };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST" 
            url: "/test/url",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data:JSON.stringify(out),
            success:function(response){
                $(this).attr("data-response",response);
                order.push(response);
                callback();
            }
        })
    })
}

$("#button").click(function(){
    sub($(".test"), function() { console.log(order) });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Add attribute async : false to your $.ajax - call. Then the calls are made in sequence after eachother.

Comment: This is a bad solution - there is a very good reason to use async calls.

Comment: that would make things even slower

Comment: Yes it would make it slower. I just answered the question and it will work. If peformance is an issue OP should rewrite the code so only one server request is done for each function call(if possible)